# jQuery Plugin return Values through options function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-plugins

I'm making my own jQuery plugin (I am still learning!). The plugin needs to return values once clicked on a certain element.

It looks along the lines of this:

```
$.fn.testPlugin = function(options) {

    var defaultOptions = {
        values: {
            value1: "",
            value2: ""
        },
        onDivNameClick: function() {}
    };
    options = $.extend(true, defaultOptions, options);

    //Do some initializing here

    divName.click(function () {

        //Do some other plugin stuff on click here

        // onClick User Function
        if ($.isFunction(options.onDivNameClick)) {
            options.onDivNameClick.call(options.values);
        }
    })

    //Other code here.


    return this;
}
```

I initialize the plugin and pass commands that I would like to be executed however the plugin does not return the values I need through `values` instead it is `'undefined'`.
Debugging shows me that `options.values` does have data inside the plugin so I'm not entirely sure this is the correct way to do it.

```
$("#elName").testPlugin({
    onDivNameClick: function (values) { //values returns 'undefined'
        model.value1 = values.value1;
        model.value2 = values.value2;
    },
    option1: "",
    //other options
});
```

`onDivNameClick` should pass `options.values` into the function in options but it currently does not. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript [`prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method needs one more parameter referring to `this`.

```
if ($.isFunction(options.onDivNameClick)) {
    options.onDivNameClick.call(this, options.values);
}
```

Because of this - no actual values were passed through the function.